# How do I get my DC motor ceiling fan to work again?

Tags: ceiling-fan, testing, remote-control

We purchased a home with a Fanimation Slinger v2 72 inch fan.  It worked fine for months.  Then it intermittently turned itself off, or ran slow for another 3 months.  now it will not turn on at all.

DIY advice on the internet had us test a few things and it looked like the problem was the receiver.

We ordered a replacement receiver but it did not fix the problem.  NOW I know it was the wrong version of the receiver.  I needed a fr-a786n-04 receiver and I had ordered the fr-***-12.

Asside: Before I made the time to return this wrong part, I misplaced it. Now even if I find it, the return widow has closed.

After the failed attempt to buy the right controller, I contacted the fan manufacturer (FANIMATION) who could not tell me anything about the receiver or how to bench test it.  So I tried the manufacturer of the receiver (Rhine Electronics) and I do not know if they really could not find the correct wiring diagrams for the receivers (there are over 20 of the assorted variation of the same device) or just can't give them to the public.  They were nice and we sent several emails, but the end result is I could not get a diagram or bench test instructions.

I live in California and the closest company I have found that will test the fan for me is  in Florida and they wanted me to ship the entire fan to them.  (taking it down , shipping, and then putting it up again is just too scary to think about.)

So I have the remote and the receiver ready to bench test.  I also have all of my dad's bench test tools, but I can't seem to find any instructions on what inputs and outputs SHOULD be with this receiver.  Dad was and engineer on a nuclear sub.  He could have opened the receiver and at least been able to make a good guess as to what should power up when, and know for certain if the receiver was working or not.  I am not nearly that talented.

Below are the details have tried to use to figure out what to do next.  I still WANT to fix this but I am just about ready to give up and order a new fan.

Many many thanks for any guidance I can get.

https://www.lowes.com/pd/Fanimation-Studio-Collection-Slinger-v2-72-in-Brushed-nickel-Integrated-LED-Indoor-Outdoor-Downrod-Mount-Ceiling-Fan-with-Light-Kit-and-Remote-9-Blade-ENERGY-STAR/1000003376  is the fan for sale at Lowes.

https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5defc719b1969710bdf73e20/t/5e39e949c1c6ce528636a139/1580853578088/genericDCRegDiagram.jpg   gives a GENERIC wiring diagram, but the

We tested all batteries and connection and AC is getting TO the receiver.
The Receiver is labeled FR-a786n-04
It has a sticker saying FN666B  Which appears to indicate it is for a FANIMATION fan.
It has the controller manufacturer's golden seal sticker saying

- Rhine Electronics CO LTD.  165
- model rh786nrw
- BLDC CEILING FAN CONTROL
- INPUT: AC120V/60HZ
- DC MOTOR 35W MAX
- LIGHT 100W MAX OR 100VA
- SHUNT: 1-1.8Ω / 70-300RPM
- U.S.A Pat P994744B2
- R.O.C Pat.1358192
- MADE IN CHINA

Comment: I encountered a few of these multispeed/ multifunction fans that would not work after installing new.  It was always an issue of having the remote "learn to communicate" with the receiver.  Sorry I don't have any info on how.  I just remember that I had to do that step.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same fan (two of them!). My remote controls have a set of DIP switches accessible inside the battery compartment. Do yours? There is a procedure required to "pair" the remote with the ceiling fan. Perhaps yours has somehow forgotten its pairing. I'd make a note (photo) of the current DIP switch setting, move a few of them, then try the pairing process. From a manual [there](https://fanimation.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/LP8147SLBL_OM.pdf), the process is:

1. Cut AC power to the fan by turning off the light switch (if you have one) or the circuit breaker. Wait several seconds.
2. Restore AC power to the fan.
3. Within 60 seconds or less after restoring power to the fan, press and hold the "SET" button on the remote. This button is found in the battery compartment.
4. Within a few seconds the fan should acknowledge that it has paired with the new remote. If the fan has a light kit successful pairing is indicated by it turning on and off the light twice; if no light kit then the fan will turn backward and then forward to indicate. This should happen within a few seconds of your pressing the SET button.

If you press any other button before SET, or if you take longer than 60 seconds after power-on to do the procedure, it will fail. Start over.

Answer (score 1):

Since you disconnected the unit, you should know which wires are for the AC input to the receiver. From the receiver, you should be able to determine, trace the wires that go to the light and motor. Supply the receiver with 120V and connect your multimeter to the wires for the light and operate the remote to see if you get a voltage reading, 120V. Do the same for the wires for the motor but set your multimeter for DC voltage.  There should be dip switches in the remote and receiver. Make sure they are lined up correctly. They should not be changed but you could have hit one when messing around with the units. Most receivers are "black boxes" and usually can't be serviced or taken apart so it might be time for a new fan.

Comment: Thanks for all the great advice.  I took it to an expert (local) who took it apart and saw lots of corrosion on half of the box.  He said it was the motor control part, not the radio link to the remote part, and he could fix it with lots of 'micro soldering' for a cost that is more than the entire fan when it is on sale (about $200).   So at least now i know i can order THAT replacement part with a great chance of having a working fan once i install it.